# monotouch symbols to show up in Instuments

Tags: xamarin.ios

Newbie to monotouch and 'native' iPhone development here. I'm trying to debug some memory leaks and having trouble doing so. My app is UIImage heavy and I'm definitely leaking them, but have trouble finding where.

Trying to use instruments to find where, but looks like I can't see the symbols, just see raw addresses. Any idea on how to get instruments to see correct callstack? Would seem to me that since monotouch doesn't JIT compile, monotouch should be able to generate symbols for the code it generates.

Example of callstack in instruments:

```
   0 libSystem.B.dylib calloc
   1 libobjc.A.dylib _internal_class_createInstanceFromZone
   2 libobjc.A.dylib class_createInstance
   3 CoreFoundation +[NSObject(NSObject) allocWithZone:]
   4 CoreFoundation +[NSObject(NSObject) alloc]
   5 UIKit GetPartImages
   6 UIKit -[UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundView _updateImages]
   7 UIKit -[UITextFieldBackgroundView initWithFrame:active:]
   8 UIKit -[UITextField setBorderStyle:]
   9  0xdf40ced
  10  0xdf41846
  11  0xdf40f0e
  12  0xdf3fc75
  13  0x88b2051
  14 iPhone mono_jit_runtime_invoke
  15 iPhone mono_runtime_invoke
  16 iPhone mono_runtime_invoke_array
  17 iPhone ves_icall_InternalInvoke
  18  0xcfc5d93
  19  0xcfc57c5
  20  0xcfc5648
  21  0xcfc9083
  22  0xcfc8f2d
  23  0xcfc8d93
  24  0xdcb02c1
  25  0xdcb025b
  26  0xdcb0034
```

Comment: Are you profiling on device or sim?

Comment: Thanks @Geoff. Missed the fact you had answered here. That doesn't seem to trigger a notification. Yes, I was trying the sim because for some reason instruments could not find my app !?!. Anyways, after further digging learned that Instruments needs dSYM symbol files. I could not figure out a way to generate them for simulator, but turns out that they were generated for device binaries, so I put some more time into trying to get Instruments to work with my app. Once it did, I was able to see good callstacks. One question, though, why aren't dSYMs generated for simulator?

Comment: We JIT on the sym, dSYMs are generated at compile time.

Comment: makes sense. Out of curiosity, why do something different for the simulator (JIT vs compile?).

Comment: The simulator and device are already hugely different, and doing a full aot for every simulator run would hugely increase the edit/compile/run cycle time.

Comment: thanks again Geoff, it is indeed much faster to iterate on simulator, so sounds like a good trade off.